# Create Sql Server Authentication Account?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I want to create an Sql Server Authentication Account, not a user in the database or in the account.

What i mean is that i want to create an account so i can login from it when i start the sql server, using SQL Transaction or using C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are only two modes that I know you can use: Windows or SQL Server Authentication. This means you are limited to only two choices: You either use a Windows account, or you create an SQL Server login that you can use to authenticate.

EDIT:

To programmatically create an sql server login, you could use Sql Server Management objects. I notice you didn't say whether you want to do this from a Windows (desktop) or Web application. To use Sql Server Management to create a login (or do any sort of "management"), the code would need to run with higher privileges - say local or domain account with sufficient privileges to administer the SQL server instance.

You will need to add references to (you could use version 9.0 of the assemblies):

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo
Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo
Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum
```

With that, the following code is enough to create an SQL login and also add the user to your target database

```
        var serverName = "."; // Your SQL Server Instance name
        var databaseName = "Test"; // Your database name
        var loginName = "testuserY"; // Your login name (should not exist - or you should add code to check if the login exists)


        Server svr = new Server(serverName);
        var db = svr.Databases[databaseName];
        if (db != null)
        {
            // You probably want to create a login and add as a user to your database
            Login login = new Login(svr, loginName);
            login.DefaultDatabase = "master"; // Logins typically have master as default database
            login.LoginType = LoginType.SqlLogin;
            login.Create("foobar", LoginCreateOptions.None); // Enter a suitable password
            login.Enable();

            User user = new User(db, loginName);
            user.UserType = UserType.SqlLogin;
            user.Login = login.Name;
            user.Create();
            // add a role
            user.AddToRole("db_owner");
        }
```

You will need to add:

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
```

You can add try{} catch{} blocks and plumbing code to make it more robust you would recover gracefully in case of failure

Comment: Ok, how to create a SQL Server login using sql transaction or using C# ?

Comment: In Sql Server 2008 R2 I could skip the call to login.Enable(): looks like the Login object gets enabled at creation.