# How to create new SQL Server 2012 login without SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I have creating my system using Entity Framework code first for it create database automatic if it is not exist, but first, I need a user for access database

But I know only create user of SQL Server with SQL Server Management Studio, but I'm in a situation, where computer have SQL Server 2012 installed, but have not SQL Server Management Studio

What can I do for create a new database user without SQL Server Management Studio? Or have any solution with Entity Framework like it create database automatic?

Answer (score 3):

To create a login from windows domain account using **SQL Server Windows Authentication**

```
CREATE LOGIN [Domain\Windows_UserName] FROM WINDOWS;
GO
```

Then you have to Create A **user with that Login**

```
CREATE USER [Domain\Windows_UserName] FOR LOGIN [Domain\Windows_UserName];
GO
```

For **Sql Server  Authentication**

```
CREATE LOGIN Login_Name WITH PASSWORD = 'ksblaksvfdh&';
GO
```

Comment: no explanation of where to enter the above commands.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL Server SMO to programatically create the database Users and add it the 1st time in your EF Code First `DatabaseInitializer`. Use with caution though ;)

Add References to the following.

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo
Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo
Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum
```

Then create an SQL login and also add the user to your target database

```
var serverName = "."; // Your SQL Server Instance name
var databaseName = "Test"; // Your database name
var loginName = "testuserY"; // Your login name (should not exist - or you should add code to check if the login exists)


Server svr = new Server(serverName);
var db = svr.Databases[databaseName];
if (db != null)
{
    // You probably want to create a login and add as a user to your database
    Login login = new Login(svr, loginName);
    login.DefaultDatabase = "master"; // Logins typically have master as default database
    login.LoginType = LoginType.SqlLogin;
    login.Create("foobar", LoginCreateOptions.None); // Enter a suitable password
    login.Enable();

    User user = new User(db, loginName);
    user.UserType = UserType.SqlLogin;
    user.Login = login.Name;
    user.Create();
    // add a role
    user.AddToRole("db_owner");
}
```

Source of Source Code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7899436/325521

Comment: this `Login` is a class in Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo? it is like login for access database?

Comment: Yes. I've used a script similar to this create database users for the application that are referenced in `web.config` of the main application. Mind you, the sql server user context under which this particular script runs has to be elevated, and have enough rights to create new users, assign schema / roles and table, object access etc. That's why I said use with caution :)