# How to check if login program supports windows authentication and sql authentication mode?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, authentication

I am currently creating a login program in c# visual studio 2015. The purpose of this program is to allow myself to login into it and then able to execute sql scripts (.sql files).

I have to make sure it supports windows authentication mode and sql authentication mode both. How do i verify this?

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // Connection string
        string cs = @"Data Source = 172.28.40.19\CASINO2008R2; Initial catalog =GCVS2_DEV_GHR; Integrated Security = True;";


        // Login click event
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            if (textBox1.Text == "" || textBox2.Text == "")
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Please provide Username and Password");
                return;

            }else



                try

            //Create sqlconnection
            {
                 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
                 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"Select * from tbl_Login WHERE Username=@username and Password=@Password", con);

                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", textBox1.Text);

                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", textBox2.Text);
                 con.Open();
                 SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                 adapt.Fill(ds);
                 con.Close();
                 int count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

                 // if count equals to 1, then show frmMain form

                 if (count == 1)
                 {

                     MessageBox.Show("Login successful");
                     this.Hide();
                     frmMain fm = new frmMain();
                     fm.Show();
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     MessageBox.Show("Login failed");
                 }
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
             }

         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code to check sql login mode :

```
DECLARE @AuthenticationMode INT  
EXEC master.dbo.xp_instance_regread N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', 
N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer',   
N'LoginMode', @AuthenticationMode OUTPUT  

SELECT CASE @AuthenticationMode    
WHEN 1 THEN 'Windows Authentication'   
WHEN 2 THEN 'Windows and SQL Server Authentication'   
ELSE 'Unknown'  
END as [Authentication Mode]
```

and for creating new SQL Login please visit

[Create Sql Server Authentication Account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899383/create-sql-server-authentication-account)

**EDIT :**

if you want to check and create SQL login the use following

```
public bool _MCheckWindowsLogin()
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;database=master"))
            {
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    return true;
                }
                catch
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        public bool _MCheckSQLLogin()
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("ConnectionStringWithSQLLogIN"))
            {
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    return true;
                }
                catch
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        public bool _MCheckLogin()
        {
            if (!_MCheckSQLLogin())
            {
                if (!_MCheckWindowsLogin())
                {
                   MessageBox.Show ("Some Error Message Here");
                    return false;
                }
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;database=master"))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    try
                    {
                        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DECLARE @D BIGINT IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT NAME FROM [master].[sys].[syslogins] WHERE name = 'YourLoginName') BEGIN SET @D = 1 END SELECT @D", con))
                        {
                            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                            {
                                if (dr.HasRows)
                                {
                                    while (dr.Read())
                                    {
                                        bool a = Convert.ToBoolean(dr[0]);
                                        dr.Close();
                                        if (a)
                                        {
                                            string Aa = @"EXEC xp_instance_regwrite N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'LoginMode', REG_DWORD, 2 ;";
                                            Aa += "CREATE LOGIN [YourLoginName] WITH PASSWORD=N'YourPassword', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF ;";
                                            Aa += "EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'YourLoginName', @rolename = N'bulkadmin' ;";
                                            Aa += "EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'YourLoginName', @rolename = N'dbcreator' ;";
                                            Aa += "EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'YourLoginName', @rolename = N'diskadmin' ;";
                                            Aa += "EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'YourLoginName', @rolename = N'processadmin' ;";
                                            Aa += "EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'YourLoginName', @rolename = N'securityadmin' ;";
                                            Aa += "EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'YourLoginName', @rolename = N'serveradmin' ;";
                                            Aa += "EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'YourLoginName', @rolename = N'sysadmin' ;";
                                            using (SqlCommand cmd8 = new SqlCommand(Aa, con))
                                            {
                                                cmd8.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                            }
                                        }
                                        con.Close();
                                        Thread.Sleep(2000);
                                        return true;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception exp)
                    {
                        con.Close();
                        MessageBox.Show(exp.Message);
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```

simply use

```
if (_MCheckLogin())
{
   //Do somthing
}
else
{
   //Do somthing
}
```

and remember, to use sql login you must have dual login mode,

Comment: It says : windows and SQL server authentication in sql server

Comment: @CookieMan this is sql statement , first make bool method in c# and execute this in c# and return true of false as desired, its just a idea

Comment: Hmm, I think there's miscommunication in my question. What I want is like creating a login function / page, and then user can choose to login with windows authetication OR sql server authentication. Is there any guideline for this case?